# ¿Cómo obtener un valor de un diccionario de diccionarios?

Tags: python

Hola a toda la comunidad, a continuación trataré de explicar lo que debe hacer mi programa por medio de un ejemplo:

Esta es la definición de la función:

```
   def calcular_estadisticas_tarea(tareas_estudiantes:dict,nombre_tarea:str)->dict:
```

Los parámetros entran de la siguiente forma:

```
    calcular_estadisticas_tarea({"Roberto": {"Tarea 1": 80, "Tarea 2" : 90},"Maria":{"Tarea 2":80},"Miguel":{"Tarea 2":30}},"Tarea 1")
```

Lo que debe hacer mi código, es buscar aquellos estudiantes que hicieron la tarea pasada como parámetro("Tarea 1" en el caso del ejemplo) y retornar un diccionario con el estudiante que saco la mayor nota en esta tarea así:

```
    [out]: {'mayor':80, 'mejor':'Roberto'}
```

Para el caso de este problema no puedo usar un break y solo puedo usar un return en el caso de que sea necesario.
Ocurre un problema y es que jamás he trabajo con diccionarios de diccionarios y jamás me han explicado como, así que aún no tengo un código base. Si alguien tiene una idea de como resolverlo y un consejo sobre como estudiar diccionarios de diccionarios me sería de mucha ayuda. Gracias.

Comment: Hola Samuel, puedes iterar sobre los diccionarios anidados usando simplemente la vista `dict.items`, algo como:  `for estudiante, tareas in tareas_estudiantes,items():` ... dónde `tareas` sera el diccionario anidado...

Answer (score 0):

El codigo a continuacion es muy basico se puede optimizar, pero para deseos de la explicacion lo hice lo mas sencillo posible.

Los diccionarios manejan llave:valor, primero debes recorrer las llaves de tu diccionario "padre", en este caso los nombres de los estudiantes, ahora bien, tomando el nombre del diccionario y llamando al valor de cada estudiante, obtienes un nuevo diccionario de sus notas, donde ahora la llave es el nombre de la tarea, y el valor la nota.

Para calcular cual es el mayor se inicia una nota maxima en 0, para que si una nota es mayor a 0 se vuelva la maxima, y despues si otra nota es mayor a la maxima encontrada anteriormente, esta sera la nueva maxima.

```
def calcular_estadisticas_tarea(tareas_estudiantes, nombre_tarea):
    mejorNota=0
    mejorEstudiante=''
    for estudiante in tareas_estudiantes:
        for tarea in tareas_estudiantes[estudiante]:
            if nombre_tarea==tarea:
                if tareas_estudiantes[estudiante][tarea]>mejorNota:
                    mejorNota=tareas_estudiantes[estudiante][tarea]
                    mejorEstudiante=estudiante
    return {'mayor':mejorNota,'mejor':mejorEstudiante}
```

Comment: Okey, ya veo como funciona, no había pensado en el uso de ciclos for anidados pero resulta muy útil, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Como mencionaron en el comentario, puedes usar las características iterables que tienen los diccionarios: [Looping Techniques](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques)

Un diccionario se comporta parecido a una *base de datos* muy básica, así que puedes consultar valores en él proporcionando un índice, como este ejemplo ejecutado desde la consola:

```
>>> colores = {'rojo':'#ff0000', 'verde':'#00ff00', 'azul':'#0000ff'}
>>> colores['verde']
'#00ff00'
>>>
>>> for key, value in colores.items():
...     print('{} --> {}'.format(key, value))
...
rojo --> #ff0000 
verde --> #00ff00 
azul --> #0000ff
>>>
>>> # puedo preguntar si existe un índice
>>> 'azul' in colores
>>> True
>>> 'naranja' in colores
>>> False
```

Ahora aplicando esos conceptos en tu función, quedaría algo como:

```
def calcular_estadisticas_tarea(tareas_estudiantes, nombre_tarea):
    max_nota = 0
    mej_estud = ''
    for estudiante, asignacion in tareas_estudiantes.items():
        if nombre_tarea in asignacion:
            if asignacion[nombre_tarea] > max_nota:
                max_nota = asignacion[nombre_tarea]
                mej_estud = estudiante
    return {'mayor':max_nota, 'mejor':mej_estud}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por el código y por la información sobre las Looping Techniques, las estaré repasando pues no las conocía y creo que serán de mucha ayuda